# can't see the change of the global variable when import a module

Tags: python

I want to implement python code that related to Problem 2-4 of third edition of CLRS .The problem is "find the number of **Inversion** s in a list  " in page 41 and I write this code:

```
mainCounter = 0
def merg(array,counter):
    if len(array)==1:
            return array
    left = array[:len(array)/2]
    right = array[len(array)/2:]
    return combine(merg(left, counter), merg(right, counter), counter)

def combine(array1, array2, counter):
    global mainCounter
    result = []
    pointer1 = 0
    pointer2 = 0
    while(pointer1 != len(array1) and pointer2 != len(array2)):
            if array1[pointer1] < array2[pointer2]:
                    result.append(array1[pointer1])
                    pointer1 += 1
            elif array1[pointer1] == array2[pointer2]:
                    result.append(array1[pointer1])
                    pointer1 += 1
            else:
                    result.append(array2[pointer2])
                    counter += (len(array1)-pointer1)
                    pointer2 += 1
    if pointer1 == len(array1):
            for i in array2[pointer2:]:
                    result.append(i)
    else:
            for i in array1[pointer1:]:
                    result.append(i)
    mainCounter+=counter
    return result
```

The problem is when I import this module in python console mainCounter doesn't change but this must be changed !!:

```
Python 2.7.3 (default, Aug  1 2012, 05:16:07) 
[GCC 4.6.3] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from mergSort import *
>>> merg([1,4,2,3],0)
0
0
2
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> merg([1,4,2,3],0)
2
2
4
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> mainCounter
0
>>> merg([1,4,2,3],0)
4
4
6
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> merg([1,4,2,3],0)
6
6
8
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> merg([1,4,2,3],0)
8
8
10
[1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> mainCounter
0
```

every time I call the `merg` function I get different results but mainCounter doesn't changed ! where I am wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

tldr: Don't use `from module import *`

`import *` is less special than you might think - when you import things with `from mergSort import *`, think of it as

```
import mergSort
mainCounter = mergSort.mainCounter
merg = mergSort.merg
del mergSort
```

So you really just have a reference to the int object that `mergSort.mainCounter` referred to when you did the import. `mergSort` uses the `mergSort.mainCounter` one; in the same way that

```
>>> a = 1
>>> b = a
>>> a += 1 # or a = a + 1 or a = a.__add__(1)
>>> a
2
>>> b
1
```

we have two separate references to integer objects, and incrementing one (changing the reference to point to a new object produced by a method call on the old object) won't effect the other. To confirm this, try

```
merg.__globals__['mainCounter']
```

or

```
import sys; sys.modules[merg.__module__].mainCounter
```

These should have the mainCounter value merg is using.

(`sys.modules['mergSort'] is merg.__globals__` is true, they're the same thing dictionary)

When a name is declared global in a function, it is looked up in the function's module's namespace.

`import *` is often maligned because it makes it very difficult to trace where a name came from, but here it's also bad because it breaks our conception of modules - just because you import * from a module doesn't mean you're actually in its namespace, you've just done `from module import a, b, c, d, e, ...`. This is made worse because many names aren't re-bound in Python much, but some are all the time, like names acting as counters by referring to integers.

Comment: ok. but why mainCounter is always 0 ?mainCounter must be changed.

Comment: `AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'mainCounter'` when try 'merg.__module__.mainCounter '

Comment: Whoops, didn't test that - fixed

Comment: thanks, then global in function not really global all over the application yes ?

Comment: correct, no real globals in Python - which is generally a Good Thing - so another module won't happen to use the same `mainCounter` name and mess yours up.

Comment: @mojibuntu does this make sense now? It'd be helpful to hear how it doesn't or be reminded what's confusing about this behavior so I can write a better answer for other people

Comment: yes. but I must to research more :D This is amazing feature in python

Comment: To make long story short : 

- **don't** use star imports
- **don't** use globals for state handling (we have objects and closures for this, don't we ?)

Comment: Meh, modules are singleton objects without inheritance and dunder methods, so if you know what you're doing it might be ok, might prevent creation of an unnecessary class - but you're probably right, when I do this I often turn them into classes later.

Answer (score 1):

It's a good practice to don't use `import *` at all.
Your imported objects don't know anything about each other and using `global mainCounter` doesn't help.

Try this:

```
import mergSort

mergSort.merg([1, 4, 2, 3], 0)
print mergSort.mainCounter
```